# Using php to parse values from a mysql dump file?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a script or class for PHP to parse the insert values from a mysql dump file? I wrote a script that massages data from an export. I want to parse all the values to do some conformance testing, and I wonder if that problem's already been solved.

For instance, in the dump file, I have

```
INSERT INTO table ( field1, field2, ... ) VALUES ( "a", "B", ...);
```

and I want to extract

```
a
B
```

to test those values and see that they're what I think they should be.

I also need this to be able to handle the extended inserts format, which is `VALUES ( "a", "B", ...), ( "c", "D", ...), ( "e", "F", ...),`.

Comment: Why don't you run the queries in a separate database so you can make these comparisons with PHP/mysql instead of parsing text?

Comment: @markus since my script massages a dump file, I'd like to keep it all self-contained (I'm also kind of testing that the script massages data correctly). If I can avoid going through the database to run the script, that'd be great. Also, since the massaged data can appear in almost any table and field, I'd have to run a query like `SELECT * FROM *` which might be a pain to construct. It's not a one-off massaging of data; this is a script that's going to be used regularly.

Comment: Well, then tell al more about your setup and requirements. Because the solution you propose seems hacky and doomed.

Comment: @Markus what specifically do you want to know? All I want is to get the `a,B,..` out of a file that has lines like `INSERT INTO ... ( "a", "B", .. )`. It's a php script running on the command line, but that's kind of irrelevant to the actual parsing.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details about where the dump file is coming from and what you plan on using the dump file for? Most likely there is a much better way to handle this than what you ask for in the question.

Comment: The dump file is coming from a mysql database. It has strings in it that are outputs of the php `serialize()` function, which could be in almost any table and field. We want to replace certain values in serialized strings, which will screw up the serialization, since the serialization indicates length, which must be recalculated if the replaced text differs in length from the original text. I wrote a script that re-calculates the length value of the updated string, and changes it. I want to unserialize and re-serialize the changed strings to see that the re-calculation worked properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php-sql-parser should do what you want. Here's a link to its manual:

http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/wiki/ParserManual

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments, I'd like to offer a few tips on what I think is the best way to handle this.

1. You shouldn't be storing serialized data in a relational database. Instead, you should normalize your data, allowing you to take full advantage of what relational databases offer. I don't know how deeply your project depends on this, but if possible, I highly recommend refactoring.
2. If you must keep storing/using serialized data (strongly recommend against this), I would consider avoiding the dump altogether, and using something like the following:

Process data in PHP, then update directly:

```
$tables = $db->query("SHOW tables");
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $table");
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $foo = unserialize($row['foo']);
        $foo = massage($foo);
        $db->query("UPDATE $table SET foo=$foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts in trying to help with this situation, but I can't use what you suggest. We're using Drupal, which stores serialized strings in the database. No getting around this. We have a process for migrating sites which involved dump files, no getting around this. Trust me, I've been through this. All I'm looking for is a PHP SQL parser, like gschwa linked to. I resisted giving background information to avoid orthogonal answers such as this. But I do appreciate it.

Comment: @user151841 well, if that comment was in the question, I wouldn't have written this :) There's also pear.php.net/SQL_Parser, but I think it has been known to have a few bugs.

Comment: My question was straightforward in asking for a PHP SQL parser. You gave me a solution to my problem, but not an answer to my question. As soon as people started asking for more background, I started to get a whiff of "dead bird" (http://naminghard.blogspot.com/2011/07/programming-metaphors-you-need-part-1.html ) 

If you post the PEAR library as an answer, I'll upvote it :)