# PHP check if row exists in .sql dump file

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering how to check if a row exists in a MYSQL .sql dump file without loading it into a database. I also wish to check 3 fields. FieldA,FieldB, FieldC with userinfo1,userinfo2,userinfo3, all of those are strings. The filename is database1.sql and is stored on an FTP server. Is there a way to do this wiht leaving the file on the other server and not importing it into another database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using php to parse values from a mysql dump file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503150/using-php-to-parse-values-from-a-mysql-dump-file)

Comment: `for $n = 0..N : ` `fseek( $n * 10000 )` `$s = fgets( 10000 + 500);` `preg_match( ..., $s )`

Comment: Have you tried opening the file on a text editor and use 'find'? Too big? Perhaps use `grep` (if you are on linux/unix)

Comment: does php have a method for that(that can search the file without actually downloading it)?

Comment: No PHP doesn't have it. To my knowledge this is impossible. The only way to achieve anything like this is is with SSH. You could so something like `ssh user@hostname cat /path/to/file | grep FieldA`. Everything after the hostname are normal linux commands.

Comment: If you have SSH access you can login to the server and run these commands. If you don't have SSH access, you could download the SQL file and upload it to your own linux environment to process it. 

Or just download it and use a text editor to search for your strings. You might be better off just downloading it, and loading it into a mysql server(you could setup wamp if run windows), if you string is encoded and saved in the database, you might not be able to do a simple search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so first of all there is no way to do any processing on the file without having it on the server where PHP is running. You can however have a PHP script which logs into the FTP and automatically downloads and processes the file.

As to the SQL processing, the easiest way is to read the file line by line, first use strpos("INSERT INTO .....) to check for the beginning of the correct query type (insert, update ... whatever it might be and then use something like:

https://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/wiki/ParserManual
and go over the generated array and compare the values. This is fairly simple and easy to do. However the library comes with some overhead so if speed is an issue or files are very big, you will need some complex preg_match regular expression to get the necessary values and checksum them. After that you can store them in a temporary array and go over this checksums array each time to match whether you already have those values...